# What should the difference of inner to outer diameter of two pipes be to ensure one fits snugly within another?

Tags: pipe, metal, plastic, fitting

One pipe is brass and the other is going to be made out of a hard plastic, probably acetal. I'm looking to be able to slide the acetal fitting over the the brass and have it snug enough so it doesn't wiggle or fall off but loose enough so you can slide it on and off with enough exertion (without needing to use a tool). My question is, what are the rules in determining what the difference between the outer diameter of the inner pipe vs the inner diameter of the outer pipe?

I found this similar question: [How can I fit a pipe inside another pipe?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/58834/how-can-i-fit-a-pipe-inside-another-pipe) but the answers were more specific to his use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no set rules across materials, all the materials have different wall thickness (thus outside diameters) based on their use (strength and durability) and other reasons. The best you can do is pick your material and look at the size charts to find something that works for your needs

Comment: I'm going to be getting the acetal piece custom made but I'm wondering how I should go about drawing up the dimensions. I assume leaving 0 space between the two cylinders wouldn't work. Although, maybe I could do that and ever so slightly sand down the inner part of the plastic as needed to make it fit?

Comment: oof, sanding the inside of the pipe sounds like a lot of hard work to get it right. Sanding down the outside of the brass would be much easier. I am not sure the tolerances that you would need to get the action that you want, though surely not zero. However, you can recover from too tight but not too loose.

Comment: OIC now, your question is about the tolerances. This is more of an engineering question, you might try the engineering stock exchange https://engineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ah true. Maybe I'll give it a go over there. And good point about sanding down the outside of the pipe slightly haha. Wasn't thinking.

Comment: Do a search for tolerances or limits and fits to get an idea.

Comment: If you integrated a couple of o-rings in grooves, you could deal with a little more slop in the fit.